# java iterator stops unexpectadely

Tags: java, android

**My code to iterate is,**

```
Iterator<BrokerDeals> it = listBrokerDeals.iterator();
ArrayList<BrokerDeals> listBrokerDeals_new = new    ArrayList<BrokerDeals>();
                    while (it.hasNext())
                    {
                        BrokerDeals deals = it.next();
                        Log.i("TRACE==","deals.ok_id"+deals.getOkId());
                        if(!(deals.getOkId().equalsIgnoreCase(null)))
                        {
                            Log.i("TRACE==","deals.ok_id inside cond");
                            listBrokerDeals_new.add(deals);
                        }

                    }

                    Log.i("TRACE==","list broker deals" +listBrokerDeals_new);
```

**My Log is**

```
04-30 08:20:28.021 28449-28449/com.o.n I/TRACE==: deals.ok_id6321r9hrr960780
04-30 08:20:28.021 28449-28449/com.o.n I/TRACE==: deals.ok_id inside cond
04-30 08:20:28.021 28449-28449/com.o.n I/TRACE==: deals.ok_idx9crv9119111a
04-30 08:20:28.021 28449-28449/com.o.n I/TRACE==: deals.ok_id inside cond
04-30 08:20:28.021 28449-28449/com.o.n I/TRACE==: deals.ok_iden27yx79ph6082241a
04-30 08:20:28.021 28449-28449/com.o.n I/TRACE==: deals.ok_id inside cond
04-30 08:20:28.021 28449-28449/com.o.n I/TRACE==: deals.ok_idkhvu42e929520
04-30 08:20:28.021 28449-28449/com.o.n I/TRACE==: deals.ok_id inside cond
04-30 08:20:28.021 28449-28449/com.o.n I/TRACE==: deals.ok_iduly4n9b9ne2071111a
04-30 08:20:28.021 28449-28449/com.o.n I/TRACE==: deals.ok_id inside cond
04-30 08:20:28.021 28449-28449/com.o.n I/TRACE==: deals.ok_idkcis9719n464179
04-30 08:20:28.021 28449-28449/com.o.n I/TRACE==: deals.ok_id inside cond
04-30 08:20:28.021 28449-28449/com.o.n I/TRACE==: deals.ok_idnull
04-30 08:20:28.871 28449-29253/com.o.n I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 137
```

As you can see in log ITERATOR STOPS when deals.ok_id() gives null   and Log.i("TRACE==","list broker deals" +listBrokerDeals_new); this never gets printed.

Any idea why program is stopping without error?

Answer (score 1):

Your code for checking if getOkId() is null is wrong.

```
if(!(deals.getOkId().equalsIgnoreCase(null)))
```

It should be:

```
if(!(deals.getOkId() == null))
```

because that method expects a non-null String. As stated in its JavaDoc:

> This method returns true if the argument is not null and the Strings
>   are equal, ignoring case; false otherwise.